# How to use and store data in session variable in controller event

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public void MqttMsgPublishReceived(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
    string ReceivedMessage = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Message);

    if (ReceivedMessage.Contains("M2MType IO"))
    {
        Session["msg"] = ReceivedMessage;  // not storing data
    }
}
```

The line

```
Session["msg"] = ReceivedMessage;
```

is not storing data into `msg`

I don't know why this happening. Please tell me how to use a session variable in the event function.

Comment: Is debugger goes inside `if` ?

Comment: yes, but not in Session["msg"] = ReceivedMessage;

Comment: how do you inspect that session does not stored data? and how you use it?

Comment: How do you know it is not storing?

Comment: actually, it is giving an error like -- Object reference not set to an instance of an object error

Comment: @RamuVishwakarma, on which line?

Comment: Regarding the error message, it's clearly a `NullReferenceException` (NRE) - please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it?rq=1) to find out and fix the problem.

Comment: @er-sho,  Session["msg"] = ReceivedMessage; on this line

Comment: Actually, I have used a session variable to store and retrieve the value in the normal function there it is working. but in an event function, as I have given in the problem is not working.

Comment: could you please check the namespace for `Session` ? Is it comes from `HttpContext` or from any other ?

Comment: do you have init session in global.asax?

protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}